# Preference item-like layout

Tags: android

In main activity of my application I need a control which should look like ListPreference in PreferencesActivity. I mean, 2 lines: title and current value and down arrow icon on the right.

I've tried to use TwoLineListItem for this:

```
<TwoLineListItem android:id="@+id/twoLineListItem1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick" android:focusable="true"
    android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:text="Upload into:" />
    <TextView android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/text1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/text2" android:text="&lt;not set&gt;"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <!-- <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:id="@android:id/selectedIcon" 
        android:src="???"> </ImageView> -->

</TwoLineListItem>
```

It all works except of arrow icon: I can't find proper resource which system uses for it.

How this could be solved?

Or maybe I should use another control instead of TwoLineListItem?

Or maybe even try to implement my activity as PreferencesActivity (thought I need some EditText controls in my activity)?

For the reference, what I need is on the left picture:
http://androinica-serve.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/evernote_comp2.png

Answer (score 2):

wow, this question is so old and i can't believe no one answered it correctly lol.  the layout you were looking for is in the sdk tree under:

`[android-sdk-root]/platforms/[your-platform]/data/res/layout/preference.xml`

you'll find this and any other sdk defined layouts in this folder.  fish around in the res folder and see what's available.  sorry it's a year late, but there ya go.

Answer (score 0):

Use this layout and modify according to your need...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:text="ggggggggg"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@android:id/text1"

       />
    <TextView android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
        android:text="ssssssssssss"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/text2" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
     </LinearLayout>

     <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
              android:id="@android:id/selectedIcon"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"
             /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! But this does not solve provlem with down arrow icon. I want to reuse system one (since it differs on emulator and my HTC device so it will be not good to declare one in my application). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using @android:drawable/btn_dropdown to get the system resource and setting that as the background.